# JQuery get text concats names

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure what's going on here but I've never seen this happen before.

I am trying to get the innerHTML of an option tag but what I am getting back are all of the selected text values instead of only the one that was just selected. Using `$(this).text()` gives me all of the options that are currently selected:

> Bill MunsonAmy HernaiAlex Antistic

If I use the element like: `$("#emp option:selected").text()`, that gives me the current option, however, if I choose a second name from the select, not only do I see the current selected text, but the name from the previous click as well.

I don't know if it matters, but all of the options were appended dynamically with JQuery.

How can I get only the current selected item and not all of them at once?

EDIT:

```
$select.on('change', function(evt, params) {
  var name  = $("#emp option:selected").text();
  alert(name); // outputs concatenated string of names
}

<select id="emp" class="chosen-select" multiple></select>
```

Comment: Sure, if I can't get a quick answer to this, I will. I didn't post any code because this seems like an easy one.

Comment: You want it to work with multiple options selectable? Else you can go for a simple dropdown

Comment: Since you are using multiple so it's working accodingly.

Comment: Is there no way for me to grab only the current value

Comment: what you mean by current value? if you select only one it will display one only.

Comment: @Alive, I can't. I'll have to look at it when I'm less exhausted. OK, so there is no easy answer to this one it seems. ugh,,

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, no, it's giving me all of the previous selections as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last selected option text in `multiple select element` also using below code:-

```
$(this).find("option:selected").last().text();
```

***Sample example:-***

```js
$("#emp").on('change',function(){
  console.log($(this).find("option:selected").last().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="emp" multiple>
  <option value="1">Bill</option>
  <option value="2">MunsonAmy</option>
  <option value="3">HernaiAlex</option>
  <option value="4">Antistic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alive! I feel alive again. :)

Comment: Sure, will do, and thanks again! I'm glad it was simple after all.

Comment: @NaN  GLAD TO HELP YOU

Comment: Thank you again, my friend!

Comment: This really doesn't work reliably; if the user selects all options and starts - for whatever reason - with the last `<option>` s/he will only ever see the text of that last (in the HTML) `<option>`.

Comment: @DavidThomas  it's working fine. I have selected all options and start unselecting one-by-one (in any order you can unselect), and it's working fine. So let me know what exactly you are telling as `doesn't work reliably`